# Conda commands fail with error "OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine."

Tags: openssl, conda, pyinstaller

I can make a new environment, but attempting to installing packages or updating conda in this env fails with the above error message.

- I've tried this on two machines with the same result.
- I've run the conda cmd terminal as administrator
- I've checked for the DLL files:
  libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll
  they are in the anaconda DLL directory
- installs and updates work fine in the base environment.
  (But I don't want to install pyinstaller in the base env. That's the whole point.)

**Here is the .condarc file contents**

```
ssl_verify: true
channels:
    - defaults
channel_priority: strict
```

**Here is a listing of the conda commands and response:**

```
(base) C:\Users\canoe>conda --version
conda 22.11.1

(base) C:\Users\canoe>conda create --name make_exe
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(base) C:\Users\canoe>conda activate make_exe

(make_exe) C:\Users\canoe>conda install pyinstaller
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

(make_exe) C:\Users\canoe>conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /t/ca-3b20be3d-a37f-415b-b133-9a5184e6128a/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

(make_exe) C:\Users\canoe>conda install openssl
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

(make_exe) C:\Users\canoe>
```

Comment: This can usually be solved by deleting your virtual enviornement and starting over

Comment: Please explain. What is a "virtual environment?" What is "starting over?" 
I had trouble updating Spyder a few months ago and had to uninstall everything conda related. That's what got me in this place where I'm trying to reinstall packages.

Comment: OK. "virtual environment" is just a conda/python environment. Yes, I've done this on two separate machines with exactly the same response.

Comment: I had a similar problem this morning after updating my conda base env, but I resolved the problem by copying the DLL files (libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll) into the anaconda/DLLs folder. Based on your comments you've already checked that these files are present in the DLLs folder ? Have you tried replacing them? i.e. copy and paste over them from here 'anaconda3>Library>bin' ? It's tagged as a closed issue on github https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11982 - if you've still got a problem maybe relaunch the bug on github.